# ParserError: Expected pragma

Tags: solidity, remix, ether

**Hi guys.**
I have got one big problem. When i try to compile my code i'm getting some kind of unusuall error.
I think everything is ok but when i try to **"node compile.js"** my main file **("inbox.sol")** everytime i'm getting same error:

> "'inbox.sol:1:1: Parser## Heading ##Error: Expected pragma, import
> directive or contract/interface/library definition.\n﻿pragma solidity
> ^0.5.10;\r\n^\n',"

I will past there my code and exactly what solidity complier says.

**Compile.js file**
[image: compile.js file]
**Inbox.sol file**

[image: inbox.sol file]

**Console and error**
[image: Console and error]

**You are my only hope guys. Please help me.**

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is because your solc-js compiler version is lower than 0.5.11 but you want the version of your contract to be higher than 0.5.11 so the compiler give error.

A simple way to solve this is change `pragma solidity ^0.5.11` to `pragma solidity ^0.5.0` or just update your solc-js compiler with `npm install solc`

Answer (score 0):

**I've uptated my solc and i changed my pragma version to ^0.5.0** Nothing get changed :/

[image]

Comment: try using change ^0.5.0 to >=0.4.0 < 0.6.0

Comment: Can you update if it work or not?

Comment: You know what?! It just has started to work. I dont know why. It even didnt need any changes.